# root user can't create a file in /usr/lib

Tags: macos, command-line, root

I am trying to follow [this advice from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365619/psycopg2-installation-error-library-not-loaded-libssl-dylib) and copy some library files from `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c` to `/usr/lib/`.

I have tried `cp`, `ln -s` and even `touch`, but they all fail. I am using the `root` credentials:

```
joyce# whoami
root
```

In the right directory:

```
joyce# pwd
/usr/lib
```

But no write operation is permitted:

```
joyce# cp /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib .
cp: ./libssl.1.0.0.dylib: Operation not permitted
joyce# ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib .
ln: ./libssl.1.0.0.dylib: Operation not permitted
joyce# touch blah
touch: blah: Operation not permitted
```

Any idea how can I write to `/usr/lib` as `root`?

Comment: `/usr/lib` is protected by SIP, can't you add it to `/usr/local/lib` and pass appropriate flags to the linker?

Comment: It worked - `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2e_1/lib`. Would you like to make it an answer so I can accept and upvote?

Comment: Surely easier to use Homebrew to link into /usr/local/lib and make the build use that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/usr/lib` is protected by SIP. Even if this wouldn't be the case, it's not the best idea to put your own stuff there as any system upgrade can wipe it.

The better place to store such stuff (or link to it) is `/usr/local/lib`. You may need to pass appropriate flags to the linker then (or you point it directly to the Cellar folder).