# Write write to /usr/lib on macOS Sierra

Tags: permission, sudo, dynamic-library

I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.5, and trying to add a library to the `usr/lib` folder (for an OpenFrameworks project I'm working on).

I've seen similar questions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238828/root-user-cant-create-a-file-in-usr-lib), [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237778/cant-write-to-usr-even-with-sudo), and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11).

However, none of the suggested answers seem to have any effect. On Sierra, it seems that when rebooting in recovery mode, there is no longer any way to access a Terminal window (unless I'm mistaken), so System Integrity Protection can't be disabled by running `csrutil disable`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The Terminal.app is available is recovery mode and so is`csrutil` .

Comment: @fd0 I wasn't able to see it when I rebooted in recovery mode - how do you get to it?

Comment: In the `Utilites` menu at the top of the screen.

Comment: Instead of installing in `/usr/lib` use `/usr/local/lib` which doesn't require to disable SIP